# NVIDIA driver causes login loop, but removing it prevents resuming from sleep

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, suspend, resume

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with an AMD processor and a GTX 1050 graphics card. I hit a login loop problem a while ago, and the only thing that resolved it was purging my NVIDIA drivers. Problem is, now I can't wake my monitor up from sleep. The computer will wake up, but the screen won't pick up a signal. Forcing a restart is the only solution I've found, aside from reinstalling NVIDIA drivers.

To install the driver, I make sure I have the NVIDIA repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
```

I then go to Software & Updates > Additional Drivers and install an "NVIDIA driver metapackage" (the only options available other than X.Org X server).

How can I either (a) keep an NVIDIA driver and avoid the login loop or (b) ditch NVIDIA but be able to resume from a sleep state?

Comment: How are you installing the NVIDIA drivers?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1225641/edit) your question and add more details.

Comment: I edited to clarify how I've installed the drivers. Hope that helps.